# How can I add documents in a collection in firebase in JS?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: My Firebase Structure]

[image: My Console]

I wanted to add the two documents' amount field.

I tried the reduce method but did not work

```
db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      total_amount = doc.data().amount;
      function sum(obj) {
      return Object.keys(obj).reduce((sum,key)=>sum+parseFloat(obj[key]||0),0);
      console.log(sum(total_amount)
}
});
});
```

and I also want to know how can I return documents in a collection as an array

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqx6k.png)

How Can I filter the amount in Firebase if the first letter is + then income or - then expenditure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `reduce` in a `forEach` loop. Try this without forEach:

```js
db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  const sum = querySnapshot.docs.reduce((a, b) => a + b.data().amount, 0)
  return sum
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but, I am getting this error`a.data is not a function` if I try to `console.log(sum)`
Instead of `return sum`

Comment: @Vivek try the updated answer. It should be `a + b.data().amount`

Comment: Thanks!! As I am a Starter, I don't know how to use promises, could you please tell me how to log the data in a promise?

Comment: @Vivek that's a large topic to talk on tbh. Checkout [this video on promises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHvZLI7Db8E). That's a nice explanation for promises.

Comment: Thanks! And I also added another query in the question could you please resolve it?

Comment: @Vivek ideally you should ask a new question if it's completely different than the original question. Else it'll be a confusion in 2 answers.

Comment: Ok, Why is this returning a promise??

Comment: [Why are the Firebase APIs asynchronous?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93#:~:text=Firebase%20APIs%20are%20sensitive%20to,thread%20without%20worrying%20about%20performance.)

Comment: Thanks for answering my query!!

Comment: [Get the Promise][1]

# How do I get the `PromiseResult` in `JS`

---

[Image][2]

# How do I filter the data in collection in Firestore


```If the first letter is "+" then I want to get filtered in Income section if the first letter is "-" then I want to get filtered in Expenditure Section```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQuHR.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSfZY.png

Comment: Please Can you @Dharmaraj answer the above query?

Comment: I cannot add it unit 90 min. So I am asking you like this

Comment: @Vivek your comments give no context.... please ask a new question with complete code and expected behaviour... I'll try to check it then.

Comment: Ok @Dharmaraj. I will do it soon

Comment: I have created a Question, could you please answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68638376/how-do-i-filter-the-data-in-documents-in-firebase-in-js-and-get-promiseresult-in