# How do I filter the data in documents in firebase in JS and get PromiseResult in a Promise

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Get the promise]

## How do I get the `PromiseResult` in `JS`

Here's the code I tried:

```
  total_amount = db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    const sum = querySnapshot.docs.reduce((a, b) => a + b.data().amount, 0)
    return sum
  });
  
  console.log(total_amount);
```

---

[image]

## How do I filter the data in collection in Firestore

`If the first letter is "+" then I want to get filtered in Income section if the first letter is "-" then I want to get filtered in Expenditure Section`

I tried this, but not working:

```
    const total_sum = querySnapshot.docs.reduce((a, b) => a + b.data().amount, 0)
    const income_sum = querySnapshot.docs.filter((item) => item > 0).reduce((a, b) => a + b.data().amount, 0)
    const expenditure_sum = querySnapshot.docs.filter((item) => item < 0).reduce((a, b) => a + b.data().amount, 0) * -1;
    return total_sum, income_sum, expenditure_sum
  });
  
  console.log(total_amount);
```

I am getting the output as `undefined`

Comment: Please add your code in the question here.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I add my code here please answer my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a few things. You appear to be calling a function that returns a promise, and before awaiting it to finalize, you log it.

You could wrap a `Promise.All()` onto it, but this requires the parent function to be `async` which might not be ideal.

So instead we declare the function as a `const` and define it as an async function
You can modify this to suite your code, but without knowing the full parent block, I can only make some assumptions.

```js
const getUsers = async()=>{
total_amount = await db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    const sum = querySnapshot.docs.reduce((a, b) => a + b.data().amount, 0)
    return sum
  });
  console.log(total_amount);
}

getusers();
```

Comment: Thanks @DIGI Byte, can you answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645727/how-do-i-filter-the-data-sent-by-firestore