# How do I filter the data sent by firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I filter the data in collection in Firestore

If the first letter is "+" then I want to get filtered in Income section if the first letter is "-" then I want to get filtered in Expenditure Section

I tried this, but not working:

```js
const getUsers = async()=>{
  total_income_amount = await db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      const sum = querySnapshot.docs.filter((item) => item > 0).reduce((a, b) => a + b.data().amount, 0)
      return sum
  })
}
```

I am getting the output as `0`

and I want the output with `two decimal places`

**EDIT**

Here's my code:

```js
total_amount = db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  var total_sum = 0;
  var income_sum = 0;
  var exp_sum = 0;
  
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => { 
        const amount = doc.data().amount;
        amount >= 0.0? income_sum += amount  :  exp_sum -= amount; 
        total_sum += amount;
  });

  return {total: total_sum, income: income_sum, expense: exp_sum }
}).finally(result => console.log("Total: ", result));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the list of values and append the values once rather than looping through it 5 times with a reduce & filter

```js
  total_amount = db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    var total_sum = 0;
    var income_sum = 0;
    var exp_sum = 0;
    
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => { 
          const amount = doc.data().amount;
          amount >= 0.0? income_sum += amount  :  exp_sum -= amount; 
          total_sum += amount;
    });

    return {total: total_sum, income: income_sum, expense: exp_sum }
})
.finally(result => console.log("TOTALS", result);
```

**EDIT**
It's not good to make major changes to your Question

but in general, you can truncate all number's to a decimal place using `toFixed()` on the final output

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

**UPDATE**

Ensure your numbers are converted to real numbers from user inputs with `Number(value)` if the `typeof` returned is not a number, you can know if it is valid or not.

Once this has been done, ensure you return the correct calls as needed as scripts also only fire once.

when rendering values inside HTML, you want to use an embedded `<span>` tag with the appropriate id tag rather than editing it via javascript

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting the result as undefined

Comment: are your values numbers or strings?

Comment: They are numbers

Comment: Sorry, It is returing a promise, but, how can I get the result? and not the promise?

Comment: check my code: I use a .finally() on the promise which reacts when the promise resolves, otherwise you need to await the result.

Comment: I am Getting `TOTAL: undefined`

Comment: then something is wrong with your current code, as I am returning an object, which all the values are defined

Comment: I made changes to the question with **EDIT**
Please check that @DIGI Byte